# Where to put Scala test data

Tags: scala, maven, testing

Let us say that part of a program processes data. For testing you have a particular version of that file.

Does the maven hierarchy specify a directory that it should be put in?

If so where?

Answer (score 7):

`src/test/resources` is the canonical place to put test resources in a maven project

See the documentation for the Maven standard directory layout [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).